# Spring Data MongoDB always identifies object as new

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have the following situation:

```
@Document
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
class DocumentClass {
private final DomainObject domainObj;
}

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
class DomainObject{
@Id
private String id;
}
```

The problem is that the spring Data mongo repository doesn't see that the is in the encapsulated object and always identifies the document instance as being for a new document. 
I would like to keep the id of the domain as the document's id. How can I do that? I've tried to add a listener but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

What I had to do is to include in the Document class, the ObjectId _id field and overwrite the save method of the Mongo repository. I've overwritten save so that it checks for the embedded id if it exists and if it exists, I take the Object id and set it to the newer "version". By doing this Spring Data identifies the object as already existing in the database.